# Run failed in Netbeans 8.2, c++ "No such file or directory" (Beginner)

Tags: c++, netbeans

I'm setting up the Netbeans IDE, and i downloaded Cygwin for the compiler, make and debugger (Windows 8.1). The problem is that when i try to debug or run, this error happens.

```
C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash: exec /cygdrive/C/Users/MyName/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Pi_1/dist/Serial/Cygwin-Windows/pi_1.exe: No such file or directory

RUN FAILED (exit value 127, total time: 90ms)
```

I don't know if i'm missing something to install or if i used wrong versions of g++, make, etc...

Comment: Do you see this binary in this directory?

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced a similar problem on other IDEs (haven't used Netbeans). It turned that the anti-virus was quarantining the executable generated after compilation. I just "whitelisted" (prevent anti-virus from scanning in future) the directory where i saved my programs, and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had such error. In my case the folder name in the project path was the reason. Try to change location of your project to something simple, like "c:\NetBeansProjects\prj1".

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me as well. The reason, as already mentioned, was that the build folder contained characters as () and spaces.
C / Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, I had the same problem when saving my projects in a different folder than the predefined one. Example: `C:\Users\username\Desktop\C_Programs\new12`. This was fixed using the predefined project folder: `C:\Users\username\Documents\ NetBeansProjects\new12`.(Windows 10)